# Button type "button" only fires on "space hit", when focusing with mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Pre: "button" is `<button type='button'>`

summary:

I have two identical buttons. I mouse-click #1. I get a click-event(#1). I hit [space]. I get a click-event. I [tab] to button #2. I press [space]. noting.
When I [tab] back to #1 and press [space] - the click-event(#1) fires.

If I mouse-click #2 - the same thing vice versa - button #2 fires on [space] button #1 not.

Mouse click always fires onClick.

Pre-answerd questions:

Is it reproduce able: YES

Browser dependent?  NO (FF,Chrom & Edge - same Picture)

Library? jQuery

Other scripts around: YES; masses but theoretically(!) not influencing.

I there a workaround? YES; if I listen to the Key-event and fire a a click when key is [space], it all works fine.

Is it sure, the button has focus? YES; :focus rule is active, debugger tells me, too

Are the test buttons complex: NO, not the above mentioned ones. Just `<button type="button">aaaa</button>`

The bonus is a `<button>` that holds a `<div>` that covers half the button: If I click the `<button>` (not the div inside), I get the same picture as above. If I click the `<div>` inside the `<button>` then space does not even fire the onClick once. Although in both cases the  gets the focus and the mouse-click fires.

I am sure, that some styling and or other scrips influence this behavior, but after hours (and destroying the framework step by step removing things), I can't find any reason.

I got stuck - any idea (what to try to find out more)?

(ironic part: I am over working the framework to make it possible to interact with keyboard only)

EDIT: based on comments: I do not post an example, because the problem persists within a big framework; I do not know what and where the error happens, so I don't know what code to share or to put in a fiddle. 
What I can do is, post a link to a test page ... Am I allowed to do this here?

EDIT: I put the button directly under BODY. This looks like that - not much:

```
<body class="ldc responsive-body site_base">
    <button id="test-space" type="button">aaaa</button>
    <button type="button">aaaa</button>
    <div class="prod" id="head-canvas">
            ...
```

The code I test the bubbling is also very simple:

```
    $("#test-space").click((evt) =>
        console.log "click", evt
    )
    $("#test-space").parents().keydown( (evt) =>
        console.log "key down", evt
    ).keyup( (evt) =>
        console.log "key up", evt
    ).keypress( (evt) =>
        console.log "key", evt
    ).click((evt) =>
        console.log "click", evt
    )
```

The output if the button gets the focus with [tab]: Keyboard events are here - no click event

```
key down 
Object { originalEvent: keydown, type: "keydown", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 486711, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:34:26
key down 
Object { originalEvent: keydown, type: "keydown", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 486711, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:34:26
key 
Object { originalEvent: keypress, type: "keypress", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 486711, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:42:26
key 
Object { originalEvent: keypress, type: "keypress", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 486711, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:42:26
key up 
Object { originalEvent: keyup, type: "keyup", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 486758, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:38:26
key up 
Object { originalEvent: keyup, type: "keyup", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 486758, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html, handleObj: {…}, … }
```

The same scenario - now with a mouse click to focus: (the first 3 entries in log; the click bcause of space hit follow the keyboard events as they should:

```
    click 
Object { originalEvent: click, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: button#test-space, relatedTarget: null, timeStamp: 1239853, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: button#test-space
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:29:26
click 
Object { originalEvent: click, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: null, timeStamp: 1239853, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:46:26
click 
Object { originalEvent: click, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: null, timeStamp: 1239853, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:46:26
key down 
Object { originalEvent: keydown, type: "keydown", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 1246023, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:34:26
key down 
Object { originalEvent: keydown, type: "keydown", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 1246023, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:34:26
key 
Object { originalEvent: keypress, type: "keypress", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 1246024, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:42:26
key 
Object { originalEvent: keypress, type: "keypress", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 1246024, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:42:26
key up 
Object { originalEvent: keyup, type: "keyup", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 1246086, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:38:26
key up 
Object { originalEvent: keyup, type: "keyup", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: undefined, timeStamp: 1246086, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:38:26
click 
Object { originalEvent: click, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: button#test-space, relatedTarget: null, timeStamp: 1246147, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: button#test-space
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:29:26
click 
Object { originalEvent: click, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base, relatedTarget: null, timeStamp: 1246147, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: body.ldc.responsive-body.site_base
, handleObj: {…}, … }
browser_test.coffee:46:26
click 
Object { originalEvent: click, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented: returnFalse(), target: button#test-space, currentTarget: html, relatedTarget: null, timeStamp: 1246147, jQuery32106522351333554319: true, delegateTarget: html, handleObj: {…}, … }
```

Comment: Share your code, ideally with a working fiddle.

Comment: Likely you may have code that prevent bubble..

Comment: @iamdlm: The problem persist within a big framework; If I knew what part to post/share - I had already isolated the problem ...

Comment: @ChristianMoen, good point - just checked: keydown, keypress and keyup bubble up to HTML click does not happen - any idea what event I should watch else?

Comment: @ChristianMoen: thx for the tip! - and it was not bubbling; it was a $body[0].addEventListener('click',fn, true) that had the error and "eat" the click.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like it's a matter of focus (the keypress events are sent to the elements in focus)

from the docs https://api.jquery.com/keypress/:

> A keypress event handler can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus. Focusable elements can vary between browsers, but form controls can always get focus so are reasonable candidates for this event type.

and if you want the keypress to trigger regardless of element, you should attach the event to the `document` as all events (should, unless `stopPropagation`) bubble up to it.

```
let handler = (e) => {
  console.log('handled!', e.target.innerHTML);
}

$('.btn').keypress(handler);
```

https://codepen.io/tegaki/pen/LYPzwgJ (complete example)

Answer (score -1):

Most likely no body else will ever have a problem like this, but just if:

**"take a look at your 'addEventListener'!",**

not just the jQuery standard Event interface.

In my case it was a very old (and erroneous) stand alone part of a script, and - like the comment says - to clean strange browser behavior. It removes (removed)  'mouse click' events, that are not preceded by a mouse down on the same element.

A keyboard hit is never. The preceding mouse down was the focus click - in my strange case.